# Re-checking a CheckedListBox based on previous selection

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

[image: screenshot]

I have a CheckedListBox, filled with key-value pairs, where users can select tags, for three different options.

I hope I can make this clear...

The user has three different options; lets call them "create 1", "create 2" and "create 3". for each of these "creates" the user can select items from a CheckedListBox (which appears at the click of a button)(which are the corresponding tags of that particular create).

What happens in the code is: the user selects first one "Create", and selects corresponding "tags" in the CheckedListBox. This selection is stored in a List variable. The user then selects "Tags" for the 2nd "create", which, again, are stored in a (different) List. And likewise for the 3rd Create.

What I would like, and am not able to do, is when the 1st create Tag button is clicked again, the appearing CheckedListBox should have those items checked which the user first selected (checked) in his first selection. In other words, if for "Create 1" the Tags "x" and "y" where checked, they should re-appear as checked when the user recalls the CheckedListBox. Even though the CheckedListBox has been used to select the tags for the tag-selection of "create 2" in the mean time. What makes it even trickier, is that tags can have been added in between.

So I would like to be able to connect the CheckedListBox values with those stored in the list variables, and check those items which occur in the List(s).

Hope it's not too confusing, and somebody has a good idea how to do this.

**Edit:**
Screenshot of (part of) my form. So each of the top left "Add" buttons make the panel in the bottom appear (which contains the CheckedListBox, among other controls). In the CheckedListbox "cbTags" Tags are selected, and the selection is stored in a variable when the "Done" button is clicked. Clicking the "Done" button also hides the panel again. When all 3 "Add" buttons have been clicked, and corresponding tags have been selected, there are 3 List variables containing key-value pairs. The problem is when one of these "add" buttons is clicked again, the checkedListBox should have those values (which are stored in one of the List variables) checked again.

**Edit2**: You can also see to the right of the CheckedListBox the controls where "Tags" can be added to the CheckedListBox. I'm not sure, and haven't yet tested, but I assume new Items are added to the bottom of the list right? Meaning the indexes of the List don't get out of order.

Comment: What kind of application is it? WebForm, WinForm, WPF?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, it's a winform

Comment: Do you mean CheckedListBox?

Comment: @OhBeWise, yeah, sorry, I meant CheckedListBox

Comment: Is everything still correct?  I wasn't sure about one thing.  Do you have two CheckedListBox objects: one with the `Create` options and another to display the `Tags` associated with the most currently selected `Create`?  Also, if you could post code and/or a screenshot of your setup that could help.  I think I understand your question, but better clarity would help.

Comment: What prevents you from looping through all items in the CheckedListBox and selecting those of them what are stored in the corresponding list?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, what prevents me is mostly my coding abillity; I tried it, but didn't seem to be able to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code source it is more difficult to specify what to do, but as Nadia suggested in comments I would also suggest.  Whenever you are about to trigger an event that changes which tags should be displayed in the CheckedListBox items, you should save off a list of indices of the checked items.  Each of your "Create" options should have one of these lists saved at some point.  Then it's a matter of resetting those tags to a checked state when they are triggered to be re-displayed.

For demonstration purposes, the following example is a simple WinForms application with three buttons to switch the CheckedListBox contents displayed, and another button to add additional items to the currently displayed list.

**Properties**

```
/// <summary>
/// The index of which dictionary Options are being displayed in the CheckedListBox.
/// </summary>
public int SourceIndex { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// The array which will contain 3 dictionaries filled with data.
/// </summary>
Dictionary<int, string>[] Options { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// An array of 3 lists (corrosponding to the Options dictionaries)
/// which will contain the indices of checked Options items.
/// </summary>
List<int>[] Checked { get; set; }
```

**Constructor**

```
/// <summary>
/// Initialize the Options and add content to each.
/// New up the Checked lists.
/// </summary>
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.SourceIndex = -1;
  this.checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;

  this.Checked = new List<int>[]
  {
    new List<int>(),
    new List<int>(),
    new List<int>(),
  };

  this.Options = new Dictionary<int,string>[3];

  // Fruit Options
  this.Options[0] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  this.Options[0].Add(0, "Apple");
  this.Options[0].Add(1, "Banana");
  this.Options[0].Add(2, "Orange");
  this.Options[0].Add(3, "Grapes");

  // Meat Options
  this.Options[1] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  this.Options[1].Add(0, "Beef");
  this.Options[1].Add(1, "Chicken");
  this.Options[1].Add(2, "Pork");
  this.Options[1].Add(3, "Lamb");

  // Drink Options
  this.Options[2] = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  this.Options[2].Add(0, "Milk");
  this.Options[2].Add(1, "Water");
  this.Options[2].Add(2, "Juice");
  this.Options[2].Add(3, "Soda");
}
```

**Events**

```
/// <summary>
/// Save the displayed option's checked items then load the Fruit options to the CheckedListBox.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Button</param>
/// <param name="e">EventArgs</param>
private void FruitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SaveCheckedStates();
  this.LoadOptions(0);
}

/// <summary>
/// Save the displayed option's checked items then load the Meat options to the CheckedListBox.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Button</param>
/// <param name="e">EventArgs</param>
private void MeatButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SaveCheckedStates();
  this.LoadOptions(1);
}

/// <summary>
/// Save the displayed option's checked items then load the Drink options to the CheckedListBox.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Button</param>
/// <param name="e">EventArgs</param>
private void DrinksButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.SaveCheckedStates();
  this.LoadOptions(2);
}

/// <summary>
/// Add an item to the currently displayed Option's items.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Button</param>
/// <param name="e">EventArgs</param>
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text) && this.SourceIndex >= 0)
  {
    int index = this.Options[this.SourceIndex].Count;
    string text = this.textBox1.Text;
    this.Options[this.SourceIndex].Add(index, text);

    this.SaveCheckedStates();
    this.LoadOptions(this.SourceIndex);
  }
}
```

**Private Helper Methods**

```
/// <summary>
/// Load the (indexed) Option's items into the CheckedListBox for display.
/// Reset the Checked state for any previously checked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="index">The index of which Option's items to load.</param>
private void LoadOptions(int index)
{
  this.SourceIndex = index;
  this.checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in this.Options[index])
  {
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
  }

  foreach (int i in this.Checked[index])
  {
    this.checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// The displayed Options are about to change.
/// Save the currently displayed Option's checked item indices.
/// </summary>
private void SaveCheckedStates()
{
  if (this.SourceIndex >= 0)
  {
    this.Checked[this.SourceIndex].Clear();

    foreach (int i in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
    {
      this.Checked[this.SourceIndex].Add(i);
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Screenshot]

**Summary**
The general idea is to refresh the `CheckedListBox.Items` Every time different contents should be displayed.  You could find a way to use data binding, but CheckedListBox won't kindly accept `Dictionary` as a source.  As is, the `foreach` loops suffice and aren't too taxing. Note that adding items to your dictionary will not compromise the indexing order, but if you plan on doing any inserting/sorting/deleting of Option items, then you'll need to compensate for those changes in your Checked indices list.

This is just a crude example.  If there are optimizations to be had, hopefully someone will edit them in.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it this way. Probably won't have the time to do it today, but I'll get back to you when I do.

Comment: Thanks again, Your very nice code example helped a lot! Thanks for taking the time @NadiaChibrikova thank you too.